# PDO functions within PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

i've been working to do some basic conversions from mysqli to pdo as a learning exercise (and to future proof of course).

Here is the code i'd like to work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Syndicate Gamers Server Officers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Syndicate Gamers Server Officer Control Page</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="submit" name="solist" value="SO List" />
      <input type="submit" name="activelist" value="Active List" />
    </form>
    <?php
      require_once "connect.php";
      function solist() {
        global $DBH
        try {
          $STH = $DBH->query('select members.name as mname, syndicate_sourcebans.sb_srvgroups.name as sbg ,groups.g_title as fg,sg_servers.server_title as resp from members inner join groups on groups.g_id=members.OrigFGrp left join sg_servers on BIN(sg_servers.server_id)=BIN(members.SOServer) left join syndicate_sourcebans.sb_admins on SteamToInt(syndicate_sourcebans.sb_admins.authid)=members.steamid left join syndicate_sourcebans.sb_srvgroups on syndicate_sourcebans.sb_srvgroups.id=members.origsbgrp where members.member_group_id=17 order by sg_servers.server_title');
          $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          $STH->execute();
          echo "<table>
          <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Original Sourcebans Group</th>
          <th>Original Forum Group</th>
          <th>Assigned Server</th>
          </tr>";
          while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['mname'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['sbg'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['fg'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['resp'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
          }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
          print $e->getMessage();
        }
        $DBH = null;
      }
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php
  $user="redacted";
  $pass="redacted";
  $dbname="redacted_db";
  $db="db.redacted.net";
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$db;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
?>
```

Using the above code will populate the data requested upon pressing the button.

In lieu of the global call, i also attempted the below, which results in no data being presented from the DB.

```
   function solist($DBH) {
```

I've made modifications based on Fred and other's suggestions (mainly actually calling the function!!! thanks all) and from reading the links he provided with much success. The only problem remaining is attempting to drop the global per the advice of many other forums.

the primary suggestion from all was to "call" the function, so i added

```
if (isset($_POST['solist']))
      {
        solist();
      }
```

to the bottom of my codeblock

Comment: improper paste, correcting. sorry

Comment: it doesnt look like you ever call on your method solist

Comment: with mysqli this worked, i click solist, the query under function solist runs and outputs data. <input type="submit" name="solist" value="SO List" /> to function solist. Am i missing something?

Comment: You probably might want to edit the second snippet so it is identical to your solist method.

Comment: Are you relying on `name="solist"` to call the function? If so, you need to do something like `if(isset($_POST['solist'])){ // call the solist function }`

Comment: It fails how? What comes after the try clause?

Comment: @fred is this specific to using PDO? this code worked fine with mysqli. I didn't modify any of the "code" i only changed the way sql was being handled. Sorry, i've just started reading a book on PDO today.   (AT)DAN the try clause is the same in both snippets  (AT)hRdCoder it matched the first one, but i've made it show the full function

Comment: @driz it still doesn't match..

Comment: You need to tell us how you're calling the function. Anything inside `function solist() {...}` will NOT happen till you "call" the function, something which isn't shown nor mentioned in your question. `echo solist();` there. Function called. If you're indeed calling it, show us where. Functions don't happen on their own, that's why they're called "functions" => http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: *"or try to use `function solist(PDO $DBH)`"* you don't need to do that. Just call the function, no need to pass a parameter, since you've already set it as global. If you're not going to declare global, then just do `function solist($DBH)`

Comment: So, problem solved? Where are we at?

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually, i just did a hard refresh on my page and it's all working. Would you mind posting your stuff in an answer so i can accept? I really appreciate all your help! this has been a great learning experience for me :)

Comment: @driz That's great and glad to hear this was resolved. Give me a moment and I will gather my comments together in order to formulate an answer, *cheers* and you're quite welcome.

Comment: @driz It has been done.

Comment: Just one thing @driz - You should have marked the newly modified code under your original question/code and marked as an **Edit:....**. Should people visit the question and see the same answer, will question it and stand at asking themselves: *"There's nothing wrong with this, why the answer?"* - It may be best if you were to rollback to your original question and if you want, post what you have now under it. *Cheers*

Comment: my apologies, ill try to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your [originally/revised posted question/code:](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28351741/2)

Since you are relying on `name="solist"` as per your submit button to call the function, you need to do something to the effect of:

```
if(isset($_POST['solist'])){ 
// call the solist function 
echo solist();
}
```

The function won't fire up on its own, it needs to be called.

---

> *"or try to use `function solist(PDO $DBH)`"*

You don't need to do that. Just call the function; there is no need to pass a parameter, since you've already set it as global.

If you're not going to declare it as global, then just do `function solist($DBH)`

Comment: The OP's code currently posted on screen was used from comments given, and did not mark it as an edit. If the DV was based on that, it needs to be retracted. The answer given here was based on OP's originally posted code that did not contain my solution and OP asked me to post it as an answer. An explanation would be beneficial so that if anything in the answer is wrong and/or false, then it will be corrected.